# Swift extension to MutableCollectionType not working with array of generic types

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have an extension on UIView that returns an array of sub-views based on meta type. This way I can query the view hierarchy for example for all UITextFields, etc.

```
extension UIView {
    func subviewsOfType<T:UIView>(_:T.Type) -> [T]? {
        ...
    }
}
```

This can be called like so:

```
let fields = loginView.subviewsOfType(UITextField.self)
```

Now, I would like to act on that array `[UITextField]` with an interface that matches the generic passed in, in other words whatever is available on UITextField, example:

```
fields.alpha = 0.3 // via UIView
fields.enabled = false // via UIControl
```

I have created extensions on `MutableCollectionType` to provide these overrides:

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element == UIView {

    var alpha:CGFloat {
        get {
            if let first = self.first {
                return first.alpha
            } else {
                return 1.0
            }
        }
        set {
            for view in self {
                view.alpha = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element == UIControl {

    var enabled:Bool {
        get {
            if let first = self.first {
                return first.enabled
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        set {
            for view in self {
                view.enabled = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use these extensions they do not work as expected. :(

Here are the variations of calling code I have tried and their errors:

[image: Ambiguous reference to member alpha]

[image: Cannot assign to property fields is let constant]

[image: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type]

[image: Ambiguous reference to member enabled]

Alternatively, I tried using methods instead of computed properties, e.g.

```
func alpha(alpha:CGFloat) -> Self {
    for view in self {
        view.alpha = alpha
    }
    return self
}
```

This "works" but includes ugly casting:

[image: Using setters]

I would prefer to use regular properties on those arrays via the `MutableCollectionType` extensions:

```
loginView.subviewsOfType(UITextField.self).enabled = true
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've constrained to exactly `UIView`, not subclasses of `UIView`. You meant this:

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element: UIView { ... }
extension MutableCollectionType where Generator.Element: UIControl { ... }
```

Note the `:` rather than `==`.

And in this particular case, you'll need `fields` to be a `var` since you mutate it:

```
if var fields = loginView.subviewsOfType(UITextField.self) {
    fields.alpha = 0.3
    fields.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: A nicer solution (IMHO) for the second problem would be to declare the setters as `nonmutating set { ... }`. Then `fields` *can* be a constant. Those setters modify only the referenced objects, not the array itself.

Comment: Agreed. Very nice addition.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks @RobNapier and thanks @MartinR for the `nonmutating tip`. You both made my weekend! :)

Comment: @RobNapier Off-topic (apologies), but if you have the time: is there any reason to ever use the `final` keyword for an immutable (`final let`), or is `final` fully redundant for immutables? There's [an open Q here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671819), and I stumbled over [your implementation of `AnySequence`](https://github.com/rnapier/MyAnySequence/blob/master/MyAnySequence.playground/Contents.swift), where you make use of `final let body: ...`. Knowing from your answers your attention to detail; is there perhaps a not-only-for-annotation reason for such a use of `final let ...`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason to use `final let`. I marked it that way in the code you link because that's what the REPL indicated that Apple had done (using `:type lookup`). That said, I've never found the code that matches what I saw in the debugger in the Swift tree (and they don't use `final let` there), so I don't know if this was a compiler optimization, or I'm looking at the wrong code, or something else.

Comment: @RobNapier I see, thanks. The only place in the Swift source that I've found the use of it is in a [class declaration in a `.sil` test file](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/SILOptimizer/redundant_load_elim.sil) for the SIL optimizer, so perhaps `final let` is now only some remnant from older Swift source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems. As [Rob already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671400/1187415), you have to restrict
the extension methods to *subclasses* of `UIView`/`UIControl`.

But then the compiler still complains on

```
if let fields = self.view.subviewsOfType(UITextField.self) {
    fields.alpha = 0.3
    fields.enabled = false
}
```

with

```
error: cannot assign to property: 'fields' is a 'let' constant
```

The reason is that setting a property is considered a *mutation* of
the array (which is a *value type*), and you cannot mutate constants.

However, the array elements itself in your case are *reference types*
(instances of a class). The setter methods mutate only the referenced objects, and leave the
array itself unchanged. Therefore you can declare the setter method
as `nonmutating`:

```
var alpha:CGFloat {
    get { ... }
    nonmutating set {
        for view in self {
            view.alpha = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And now the above code compiles and works without problems.

Comment: Sadly, `nonmutating` is not very well documented.