# Is it impossible to override a constant stored property?

Tags: swift, properties, overriding, constants

I know (from the compiler's errors) that a constant property cannot be overridden by a constant, nor can it be overridden by the getter of a computed property. Obviously they can't be overridden by anything non-constant. There's no reason to add observers to them, either, since they'll never change. And yet `final let` seems to be a thing.

Is it impossible to override a stored constant property? Is `final let` exactly equivalent to `let`?

Comment: If you want each subclass to provide a constant value for a property, better turn that into a protocol instead. You mark something `final` when you don't want it to be overridden so why overriding it now?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I don't want to override; just a theoretical question. I'm wondering if `final let` actually does anything, and if not, why it's part of the language.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. `final let` is the same thing as `let`. `final var` is different from `var` though.

Comment: I think it's a valid question; since immutables can't be computed properties, there's really no reason to allow the `final` keyword for them, and it should be considered redundant (and hence, in a clever language such as Swift, possibly disallowed?).

Comment: @CodeDifferent if you can find a source for that I'd love for you to post it as an answer so I can accept.